# Is this mathematical correct? Fraction with functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have a fraction a $\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)g(x)}$, where $f$ and $g$ are functions.

Is it mathematical correct to let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and write $\frac{f(x)}{1+h(x)}$?

Or must I also remove $f(x)$ from the numerator and write $\frac{\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}}{1+h(x)}$?

Comment: Writing $f(x)/(1+h(x))$ is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Both are "mathematically correct". You are simply expressing $f(x)g(x)$ (a function of $x$) as something else. You have to be somewhat careful about writing $\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$, as this may not be well defined (specifically if there is a case where $g(x) = 0$.